# Setting cookie in HEAD

Tags: php, head

I have build a PHP plugin that creates two cookies on site load (if cookie doesn't exist).

The nature of the cookies is to store screen width and density to use within the site, which is why it is necessary for them to be created before the site content is loaded.

The problem is I am seeing a considerable delay in the site loading, as the creation of the cookies is blocking the site load...

Can anyone see anyone to optimise my function to speed up the process? or any alternative ideas?

```
public function cookie()
    {
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['screenwidth'])) 
        {
            return "<script>
                        document.cookie='screenwidth='+document.documentElement.clientWidth+'; path=/';location.reload(true);
                    </script>";
        }

        if(!isset($_COOKIE['retina'])) 
        {
            return "<script>
                        var mediaQuery = '(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),\
                                          (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),\
                                          (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),\
                                          (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)';

                        if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1 || window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
                            document.cookie='retina=yes; path=/';location.reload(true);
                        } else {
                            document.cookie='retina=no; path=/';location.reload(true);
                        }
                    </script>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: why aren't you used in the build in cookie functionality of php? http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: @MartinMandl I need to use javascript to get the client screen width etc. Do you not think this is the best way? whats your recommendation?

Comment: Personally - when I see the described performance hit - I would try using javaScript to determine the screen with, notify the server (ajax, or just with the next post/get request), and set the cookie using php ...

Comment: Would you be willing to create a little demonstration? After reading through the documentation on PHP cookies I am not entirely sure how to set a cookie that way, or at least how to get the javascript value to it.